# Can BJT transistors be damaged by static electricity?

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, esd, antistatic

I'm wondering whether they should be stored in anti-static bags or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BJT's are rarely affected by ESD, but it never hurts to keep them in an antistatic bag if you have one lying around.

Mind you that (MOS)FET's can be extremely sensitive to ESD, although they look exactly the same on the outside.

Comment: I agree that they are rarely destroyed by ESD, but affected they are. If you were to measure the parameters you will find deviations if they were exposed to ESD.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. All active components, and even passives (to a lesser extent) can be damaged by Electrostatic Discharge. The high voltage effects can start from causing parameters to deviate to complete device failures.

There is an excellent [EEVBLOG video](http://www.eevblog.com/2012/02/25/eevblog-247-anti-static-bag-myth-revisted/) describing static bags and you can see why they're helpful.

Comment: +1 for the link to Dave Jone's video, worth watching for those who want to see an example the problems ESD issues can cause.

Comment: It was one of the first time I've actually seen anyone measure the voltage.